# Solve this system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a system from Shilov's Linear Algebra, page 7

He gives a system of linear equation

$a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}=b_{1}$

$a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}=b_{2}$

He says that "eliminating one of the unknowns in the usual way, we can easily obtain the formulas":

$x_{1}=\dfrac{b_{1}a_{22}-b_{2}a_{12}}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}}$

$x_{2}=\dfrac{a_{11}b_{2}-a_{21}b_{1}}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}}$

So far, I have only been able to come up with:

$$x_{1}=\dfrac{b_{1}-a_{12}x_{2}}{a_{11}}$$
$$x_{1}=\dfrac{b_{2}-a_{22}x_{2}}{a_{21}}$$

How do you successfully eliminate the unknowns to obtain his result?

Comment: I've fixed the typo in your last equation. Just equate the last two, to get $x_2$. Then get $x_1$

Answer (score 2):

Given

$a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}=b_{1}$ and

$a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}=b_{2}$,

to eliminate $x_2$, multiply the first equation by $a_{22}$ and the second by $a_{12}$ to get

$a_{22}a_{11}x_1+a_{22}a_{12}x_2=a_{22}b_1$ and

$a_{12}a_{21}x_1+a_{12}a_{22}x_2=a_{12}b_2$

and then subtract the second equation from the first.  Can you take it from here?

A similar strategy could be used to eliminate $x_1$ and solve for $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the answer of Tanner, I tried to multiply $a_{21} (a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}=b_{1})$ and $a_{11} (a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}=b_{2})$ to get two equations:

$a_{21}a_{11}x_{1}+a_{21}a_{12}x_{2}=a_{21}b_{1}$

$a_{11}a_{21}x_{1}+a_{11}a_{22}x_{2}=a_{11}b_{2}$

The term $a_{21}a_{11}x_{1}$ cancels after substraction, the equation is $a_{21}a_{12}x_{2}-a_{11}a_{22}x_{2}=a_{21}b_{1}-a_{11}b_{2}$

Therefore $x_{2}=\dfrac{a_{21}b_{1}-a_{11}b_{2}}{a_{21}a_{12}-a_{11}a_{22}}$

Something is not right since the answer in the book is

$x_{2}=\dfrac{a_{11}b_{2}-a_{21}b_{1}}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}}$

My answer is incorrect for some reasons, can you explain where is my mistake?

Should I switch the equation or what?

Comment: Your answer is correct; you could multiply it by $\dfrac{-1}{-1}=1$ to get the book's answer

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, you could follow the multiplications indicated in these factors with $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$. Observe: $a_{11}b_{2} - a_{21}b_{2}$ indicates that the first equation was multiplied by $- a_{21}$ and the second equation was multiplied by $a_{11}$, then he added the results and isolated the value of $x_{2}$. Try to do the same to get the value of $x_{1}$.

Comment: The sign is not right when I applied your suggestion.

Comment: It worked here, may I ask you to try again? Feel free to post the steps you followed and I check if there is a mistake (mine or yours).

Comment: I will try your way tomorrow and post a detailed answer for you to criticize

Comment: Ok. You've already done this. Tanner wrote the same thing I wrote, but with more details. This is a method to solve linear systems, try to understand how you can solve a $3\times 3$ system  in the same way you did with a $2\times 2$ system. It'll be a better way to employ your time.

Comment: I am trying to learn linear algebra. The text of Shilov is very dense and I have to slog through each page. It is a nightmare, but I am confident that this will give me a better foundation for advanced calculus.

Comment: I believe that once I have learnt how to use matrix in linear algebra, I will be able to solve systems of linear equations faster.

Answer (score 0):

With "the usual way" I would understand adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying with constants or even whole terms.

The way I would do it is this one:

1. Divide each equation with their $x_1$ coefficient.
2. Subtract 2nd from 1st equation.
3. Repeat the procedure for $x_2$.

After the first step I get:
$$x_1 + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2 = \frac{b_1}{a_{11}}$$
$$x_1 + \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}x_2 = \frac{b_2}{a_{21}}$$
After 2nd step:
$$\big(\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}} - \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}\big)x_2 = \frac{b_1}{a_{11}} - \frac{b_2}{a_{21}}$$
If I divide by the constant factor before $x_2$, it just looks like the formula which is mentioned in the question.

I guess, this is exactly what the Gauß algorithm would do, but my solution was just created intuitively.